# Why js file is not working in my flask app?

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a file which is chatbot.js and I am running to run it in my flask app. But it's not visible. What should I do?

Code of JS File:

```
<!-- Start of ChatBot (www.chatbot.com) code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.__be = window.__be || {};
    window.__be.id = "60f9754b21a44e0007907430";
    (function() {
        var be = document.createElement('script'); be.type = 'text/javascript'; be.async = true;
        be.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'cdn.chatbot.com/widget/plugin.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(be, s);
    })();
</script>
<!-- End of ChatBot code -->
```

This is how I am running it into my flask application:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/js/chatbot.js') }}"></script>
```

File location:

[image]

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: See the red underline in Pycharm? It means there is a syntax error in the JS file. Indeed, `<script type="text/javascript">` is **not** valid javascript

Comment: Thanks @DeepSpace, but if try running the JS file it's working fine. I never modified that file, it's directly generated from chatbot.com. Code seems to run fine on online compilers like js.do

Comment: Either use this code snippet in html file where you are including the file or remove `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` from js file. You can see there will be an error in browser console.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It working after I removed `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` from js file. Thanks @charchit and @DeepSpace.